# First-order logic formula understanding from Blackburn and Bos

Tags: first-order-logic

I am reading Blackburn and Bos "Representation and Inference for Natural Language". It has the following formula:

$CUSTOMER(x) \vee \forall x (ROBBER(x) \wedge \forall y PERSON(y)).$

I am trying to understand what it means. 
Does it say that x either customer or (robber and person)? If so can I write it in the following form:

$CUSTOMER(x) \vee (ROBBER(x) \wedge PERSON(x)).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says that $x$ is either a costumer, or otherwise everything satisfies the following:
it is a robber and everything is a person.

Comment: Ok, I guess it is pure illustrative example without much of sense.